# Find the minimum distance from the point

Tags: calculus, optimization, maxima-minima, substitution

Find the minimum distance from the point $ \ (5,0) \ $ to the curve $ \ y=\sqrt x+2 \ $.

**Answer:**

Let $ \ (x,y) \ $ be the closest point on $ \ y=\sqrt x+2 \ $ from $  (5,0) $ .

Then the distance is given by

$ d(x,y)=\sqrt{(x-5)^2+y^2} \ $

We will minimize the function $ \ g(x,y)=(x-5)^2+y^2 \ $

replacing $ y \ \ by \ \ \sqrt x+2 \ $ , we get

$ g(x)=(x-5)^2+(\sqrt x+2)^2 \ $

The extreme points \ are

$ f'(x)=0 \\  2(x-5)+\frac{\sqrt x+2}{\sqrt x} =0 \\ 2x \sqrt x-9 \sqrt x+2=0 $

**This becomes complicated . I am  unable to calculate the closest point.**

**Help me out**

Answer (score 2):

Now, let $\sqrt{x}=t$.

Thus,$$2x\sqrt{x}-9\sqrt{x}+2=2t^3-9t+2=2t^3-4t^2+4t^2-8t-t+2=$$
$$=(t-2)(2t^2+4t-1).$$
Thus, $x_{min}=4$ and $x_{max}=\left(\sqrt{1.5}-1\right)^2.$

Also, we need to check, what happens for $x=0$.

Comment: what would be the closest point ?

Comment: @yourmath I got $(4,4)$ and the answer $\sqrt{17}$.

Answer (score 1):

write your last equation as $$2x-10+1+\frac{2}{\sqrt{x}}=0$$ and Isolate the term with the square root:
$$\frac{2}{\sqrt{x}}=-2x+9$$ squaring gives
$$\frac{4}{x}=(-2x+9)^2$$
can you finish?
factorizing the last equation gives $$- \left( x-4 \right)  \left( 4\,{x}^{2}-20\,x+1 \right) =0$$

Comment: what would be the closest point to $ (5,0) \ $ ?

Comment: it is $\sqrt{17}$ for $x=4$

Comment: I  need the closest point $ (x,y) $ from $ (5,0) \ $

Comment: wti $x=4$ one get $y=\sqrt{4}+2=4$

Comment: the solutions are $ x=4, \ x=4.94 , \ x=0.05 \ $ . Thus $ y=4, \ y=4.22, \ y=2.22 \ $ i.e., the points are $ ( 4,4) , (4.94,4.22) , (0.05,2.22) \ $

Comment: from where do you get this? there is only one point

Comment: I got it from your last equation

Comment: but there is only one Minimum!

Comment: you can make the second derivative test!